# Numpy concatenate function causes Jupyter kernel to die

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am preparing a dataset to be used for machine learning, this involves getting several numpy arrays of images, grouping arrays belonging to the same subjects together then converting them into numpy array (one per subject). I then concatenate the arrays of the subjects I want to train on to create the training inputs. My images are of size 640x480. For some reason, the concatenate function keeps causing my Jupyter notebook kernel to die.

Code snippet:

```
sub1_inps = np.array(inps0+inps1+inps2).astype(np.float32)
sub2_inps = np.array(inps3).astype(np.float32) #for testing 
sub3_inps = np.array(inps4+inps5+inps6).astype(np.float32) 
sub4_inps = np.array(inps7+inps8+inps9).astype(np.float32) 
sub5_inps = np.array(inps10+inps11+inps12).astype(np.float32)

train_inputs = np.concatenate((sub1_inps, sub3_inps, sub4_inps, sub5_inps), axis=0)#kernel dies here
```

Would anyone have an inkling regarding why this is happening?

Edit:

Each subject array contains around 7,000-10,000 images
Shapes of different subject arrays:

```
(10560, 480, 640),
(10500, 480, 640),#test set
(8040, 480, 640),
(10230, 480, 640),
(7110, 480, 640)
```

Their types are `numpy.ndarray`

`inps` are python lists

Comment: I'm guessing a memory error.  The result is too big for memory.  Sometimes that kills the run rather than issue an error message.  But without knowledge about your arrays I can't say for sure.

Comment: Please add some information about the size of the array as well as their types. If possible, please show a minimal working example.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I added in an edit

Comment: @hpaulj edited the question

Comment: np.concatenate will need a contiguous memory region to hold all your data. Since you have about 14Gb of data, it will be very difficult to find a contiguous region of memory for all that data (consider that, since you already have the images loaded somewhere else in memory, the operation will use at least 28 Gb. Depending on the framework you are using, there are functions ready to handle large training sets and load them in memory only piece by piece.

Comment: Assuming you use float32 types, it is actually huge: `4*640*480*(10560+10500+8040+10230+7110)/1024**3 ~= 53` Gio of memory for all the array without to mention temporary one (likely twice the amount of memory).

Comment: @nonDucor I am preparing this dataset to use with PyTorch

Comment: @JérômeRichard any advice how to prepare this dataset to use with PyTorch?

Comment: @JérômeRichard, you are right, I came back to fix it but you were faster!

Comment: @MohamedMoustafa, I've never usar `pytorch` but I suggest looking at `DataSet`s and `DataLoader`s.

Comment: @JérômeRichard forgot to mention that my images are gray scale (one channel)

Comment: @JérômeRichard I am running Jupyter on Linux and when I see the ```free``` command I notice that the kernel crashes when the ```swap``` memory runs out, however ```main``` still has memory that isnt being used

Answer (score 1):

I found small hack and it works . Following is the example:-

suppose I have two array variable name ary1 and ary2

```
ary1 = (2000, 5, 2000, 2000) #size / shape

ary2 = (2000, 5, 2000, 2000) #size / shape
```

now you have to create empty list and attach two array inside empty list by using "extend". Later you convert list to numpy array.

```
empty_list=[]

empty_list.extend(ary1)

empty_list.extend(ary2)

empty_list_ary=np.array(empty_list)
```

Hopefully, this would help.